# Equivalence of natural and left outer join

Tags: sql, database

According to equivalence rules(in query optimization) in database. Under what condition selection over left-outer-join is equivalent to selection over natural-join.

```
Query 1:
select * from E1 natural join E2 where E1.A>10

Query 2:
select * from E1 left outer join E2 on E1.B=E2.C where E1.A>10

Ie. sigma(theta){E1 leftouterjoin E2} is equivalent to sigma(theta){E1 natural-join E2}
```

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: Why im getting the negative reputation for this quest. Can anybody explain.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this looks like some kind of exam question, also there is no research effort in the question.

Comment: I have done a lot of research...... did not put here..now I am updating  the question with all details....

Comment: A `left join` should have an `on` clause which seems to be absent in query 2.

Comment: Yes, you need an ON clause in your outer join. Once you have that, if you filter (WHERE) on NOT NULL on the join column, it's equivalent to an inner join.

Comment: This is an exam question, right?

Comment: Just throwing this out there from a SQL DBA perspective.  You should never use a natural join, it's just laziness to not type out the explicit join, not to mention it doesn't even work on SQL Server.  Always be explicit with how you want the join to occur and what fields should be considered as matching criteria.  This is definitely a homework question as I've never heard of anyone actually using natural joins.